# BitmapFactory.decodeResource() not getting right dpi

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-resources, bitmapfactory

I'm using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` to get a bitmap from a drawable but i'm always getting the mdpi size of it. my drawable sizes are:

`mdpi - 200x400`

`hdpi - 400x600`

`xhdpi - 600 x 800`

`xxhdpi - 800 x 1200`

I'm using a 10" tablet and after logging the size of the bitmap the result i'm getting is `200x400`. Am i doing something wrong? thanks in advance

**Edit**

Here's my code

```
private void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    Log.d(TAG, bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
    drawPad.setBackgroundBitmap(bitmap);
    drawPad.clear();
    if (bottomSheetLayout.isSheetShowing())
        bottomSheetLayout.dismissSheet();
}
```

and i'm calling this

`setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.something));`

Comment: Post your actual code, and the actual dimensions of the device.  Please note that higher dpi and bigger devices aren't 100 percent correlated-  there are 10 inch tablets out there which are mdpi, particularly older devices.

Comment: @GabeSechan i tried to check the `densityDpi` from `DisplayMetrics` and yes it's mdpi. is this really ok? i mean is there some other ways?

Comment: Well, its working as expected.  You can request a particular version of a bitmap if you want, but I'm not sure I'd suggest it.  Another solution would be to use sw drawable folders (shortest width).  That's easier to separate tablet vs phone with

Comment: thanks @GabeSechan !

Comment: @GabeSechan then using sw drawable folders than dpi drawable folders are more effective?